# How do I auto play Audio files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, audio

Heres what I have:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:***AUDIOFILE*** ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] 
                                                                     error:NULL];
    [theAudio play];
```

The coding is fine, except I don't know how to call out my resource for the sound to play or whatever.

Comment: You won't play an audio file in Xcode ever — it is just an IDE

Answer (score 0):

If your Audio file is inside your project then you just need to give **Filename** without extension in place of ******AUDIOFILE******.

It is good practice to use `[theAudio prepareToPlay]` method for [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).